# Downloaded project from Github, rails server won't start

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Downloaded a project from Github and I am having issues getting the rails server to start. I ran the bundle install and am definitely in the right directory, is there anything that I've missed that you're supposed to do?

http://pastebin.com/rjhkQkZk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid, stupid noob mistake - it's with sinatra not rails. Sorry to waste your time, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Run `rails server`. If there is another error, please provide more information:

- Operating System
- Rails Version
- Log

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are at the root (directory) of the project you downloaded. And then try this command:

```
rails s
```

It would be really nice if we could learn what your log entries say.

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal set the ruby source and go to the Root directory.

hit `rails s` or `rails server`